# How to show a DNN module in a Fancybox pop up?

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, fancybox, dotnetnuke

I have a custom DNN registration and login module which I would like to pop up in a fancybox when someone clicks on the **sign in to buy** (Add to Cart) button.

Firstly, it would show a login and registration button in the pop up.
After someone has clicked on one of these buttons, the fancybox should stay open without any postbacks and show the custom DNN modules. Would I perhaps be able to achieve this with Knockout.js?

Currently, the button would add the product to your cart and redirect you away from the page to the login/registration page.

I would like the user to stay on the product page without ever leaving it.

I am thinking of adding the login and registration module to the products page and hiding the view.ascx and somehow make it pop up once the **sign in to buy button** has been clicked.

How can I make the Login/Registration module in the Fancybox do a postback? Should I use Ajax? Would the popup stay open?

Someone would probably suggest I use the DNN Modal but is it mobile friendly as a fancy box pop-up?

**UPDATE**

I have asked another question regarding the use of other existing modules in a new module: [How can I import an existing DNN module into a new module without copying the existing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434328/how-can-i-import-an-existing-dnn-module-into-a-new-module-without-copying-the-ex)

Comment: You could use an iframe in the Fancybox. That iframe points to a page with a single module and a skin with no markup. Otherwise you will indeed have to use an Ajax solution of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in login module, and simply place it inside the modal. The login module by default will simply log users in on the current page, therefore you wouldn't need to worry about the postback. I've used Bootstrap for the modal to accomplish this and it works fine.

If you needed the postback, to take users to a different page after having logged in, you could add the `?returnurl=` query string. Just make sure that the query string is already "applied" before the users actually login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We can't really use the DNN login module as we had to develop one so that our users can type in their email address, password and based on this the information is checked against our ERP system. We would then log in a user on DNN and against our ERP system.