# How can I import an existing DNN module into a new module without copying the existing code?

Tags: c#, html, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I would like to create a **new** module which will have two dropdown menu's in the settings whereby it will get the **moduleID** of two other modules that is already installed on DNN.

How would I "import" these modules into a new module without having to copy the code? I would like to hide the view of these two modules until someone clicks on a button to show them in a pop-up.

**UPDATE**

This is the original question of what I would like to achieve:
[How to show a DNN module in a Fancybox pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422453/how-to-show-a-dnn-module-in-a-fancybox-pop-up)

Comment: Not so sure of what you're trying to achieve, but... Notice you can reuse your `ascx` files across multiple modules through he DNN manifest file, thus getting different modules based on the same code.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. I have a button on a page which would trigger my new module to bring up a fancybox pop-up with existing modules showing within this window. I will investigate further. I posted another question explaining what I want to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422453/how-to-show-a-dnn-module-in-a-fancybox-pop-up

Comment: I agree with @MarioVázquez. I do not understand this quesiton. But if you want a snippet to find installed modules I can give you that.

Comment: @VDWWD That would be very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can get your module to manage this behaviour by itself, showing only if the button has been clicked. I've incorporated this behaviour to several modules as a setting option. From the configuration you can select if they should be shown as a popup or as a regular module. Check [this](https://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/algid-contact) simple one to see if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. A snippet to get the Portal Modules.

```
var allModules = DesktopModuleController.GetPortalDesktopModules(PortalId);

foreach (var module in allModules)
{
    var moduleInfo = module.Value; //because allModules is a List<KeyValuePair>

    Label1.Text += moduleInfo.DesktopModuleID + " - " + moduleInfo.FriendlyName + "<br>";
}
```